# VSCode Omnisharp ignores format settings in omnisharp.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, omnisharp

I've been working on a project in Unity for months now and have been using Omnisharp to format C# code. Just today, the formatter started formatting my code differently than before and I don't know why.

The only thing I've noticed that is different is the inserting of a new line before braces in class and method definitions, `if`/`then` statements, and loops. Before, I had it configured to format all of those things like this:

[image]

Now suddenly today they're all being formatted like this:

[image]

With a new line after the `Start()` and before the opening curly brace. The `omnisharp.json` file at the root of the project looks like this:

[image]

I haven't changed it since starting to work on this project. I would like to know why the formatter seems to suddenly ignore the `NewLine...` settings. Intellisense is still working and files are indeed being formatted, just not in a way that matches the settings I have configured.

I tried changing indentationSize to 4 in the `omnisharp.json` and restarted Omnisharp. That worked and made it indent 4 spaces. So it seems the formatter is getting something from my `omnisharp.json`, but it's just ignoring all the `NewLine...` settings when it wasn't before.

It's not a huge deal, it's just a little annoying to have my code being formatted differently than it has been all this time, and more annoying to not know why that's happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had the same issue, found a github issue with a workaround that worked for me https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5446

> I rolled back to the VS Code C# extension `v1.25.0` and this fixed the issue.

Reinstalling the C# extension to `v1.25.0` from `v1.25.2` fixed it for me.

My understanding is that the newly added omnisharp setting "Enable Editor Config Support" is on by default which makes it ignore any `omnisharp.json`s  you may have.

Answer (score 6):

"Enable Editor Config Support" mentioned by @obezy fixed the problem for me. I had updated VS Code, and when I did, omnisharp started ignoring my formatting choices.

Settings -> Extensions -> C# Configuration -> Uncheck "Omnisharp: Enable Editor Config Support"

Make sure to restart omnisharp after making the change.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings.json and remove `"omnisharp.path": "latest"` if you have it, this fixed the issue for me
make sure to restart omnisharp after by pressing `ctrl+shift+p` and type `restart omnisharp`

Answer (score 2):

Disabling `Omnisharp: Enable Editor Config Support` fixed it for me, thanks @obezy and @puzzl

Answer (score -1):

I found the list of changes and there is such an item:

> What's new in 1.25.1:
>
> When **.editorconfig** support is enabled (on by
> default), it is given higher priority over the legacy
> **omnisharp.json** code formatting options. If you would like to have the **omnisharp.json** code formatting options respected, disable
> **.editorconfig** support by setting **"omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport": false**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Useless answer when you just lift text from a document. Where is .editorconfig? How do  you disable it? Please do better next time.